# Low FPS in the ListView with ImageView

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView with the custom ArrayAdapter. It have one ImageView and couple TextViews.
I use Cache for downloading and saving Images.

I created round corners for ImageView, used this code:

```
Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
    final float roundPx = 15;

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
```

And I use this code in Cache class in the ArrayAdapter.

When I moved list up\down I have low FPS(frame per second)

Condition: All images must be saved in real size and without any changes.
On the screen at the same time present 7 - 8 items.
Testing device: Samsung Galaxy Tab p1000.

Comment: You do creating the bitmaps in real time? How about modifying the images directly after you downloaded it and save the modified version only? You should measure the time your code need for creating one image, than you see the reason for the low fps...

Comment: My guess would be that you're doing some heavy lifting in the getView() method of your Adapter - this method needs to be really lean and mean otherwise you'll get very jerky scrolling. See http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/623 and http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/632 for more info on improving ListView performance.